# Query based on sum result of grand-grand-child attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Let's suppose where have the following tables

```
orders
purchases
payments
payment_items
```

With the following relations

```
order has_many purchases
purchase has_many payments
payment has_many payment_items
```

`payment_item` has an attribute called `amount`

I would like to select all `orders` where the sum of the `amount` of all `payment_items` of all `payments` of all `purchases` are equal to 0

I am quite curious, is it possible to achieve that with an active directory query?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```rb
Order.
  joins(purchases: {payments: :payment_items}).
  select("orders.*, sum(payment_items.amount) as pmt_sum").
  group(:order_id).
  having("pmt_sum = 0")
```

Does that give you the orders you expect?

Comment: `select("sum(payment_items.amount) as pmt_sum").` will only select that column so the result will not be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Just setup an indirect association:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :purchases
  has_many :payments, through: :purcharses
  has_many :payment_items, through: :payments
end
```

```
Order.left_joins(:payment_items)
     .group(:id)
     .having(PaymentItem.arel_table[:amount].sum.eq(0))
```